# Query to get data not present in multiple arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi I have User Schema like this:-

```
var userSchema   = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, default: null},
    location: {
      type: { type: String },
      coordinates: [Number],
    },
    sentFriendRequests: [
        {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'}],
    receivedFriendRequests: [
        {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'}] 
});
```

It is working good for all the requirements. I am searching nearby users with this query:-

```
User.aggregate(
      [{
        $geoNear: {
          near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ longitude , latitude ] },
          distanceField: "dist.calculated",
          num: 5,
          spherical: true
        }
      }], function(err, nearByUsers){
         console.log(nearByUsers);
      })
```

The above query is working very good But now i want to search only the users who are not my in my friends array and not in both sent and received friend request array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well assuming you have the user document (because you're using its coordinates) then just add a $match to filter out the users before the $geonear phase.

```
{ 
  $match: {
         $and: [
           { _id: {$nin: user.sentFriendRequests},
           { _id: {$nin: user.receivedFriendRequests}
          ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @tom slabbaert. It works but If i use it before $geonear then it gives a warning that $geonear is only valid as the first stage in the pipeline. Then i used it after the $geonear phase and it works.